# Why does UIView has its own CGContext, but CALayer does not?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have trying to do some complicated drawing by swift. What I am trying to do is that I first draw my CGPath on a CALayer, and that add the CALayer on to the bottom view. (Since I need to use different blend mode in the CALayer and between different CALayers) However, I am found there is a significant difference in CALayer's draw function and that of UIView

```
//UIView's draw function
func draw(_ rect: CGRect)
//CALayer's draw function
func draw(in ctx: CGContext)
```

I have noticed that I have to give CALayer a CGContext, does it mean that CALayer can not draw itself? What's the difference between the drawing of UIView and that of CALayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give the layer a context. It has a context already; when it calls `draw(in:)` it simply hands you a reference to that context so you can draw in it explicitly. This is actually nicer than what a view does, because with a view, you have to get a reference to the context by calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext.

Still, there is usually no need to use the layer's draw method if the layer belongs to a view — because you've got the view draw method instead. A layer draw method is usually needed only when the layer is *not* a view's underlaying layer.

Please note that you never *call* either of those methods! They are called for you. What you do is *implement* them so that when they are called, you are there, ready to say what drawing should go into the view / layer.